# Azure Function PostBuild File Copy being lost

Tags: entity-framework-core, msbuild, azure-functions

I'm doing an MSBuild in Visual Studio of a C# Azure Function.  Most of the content is placed in $(TargetDir)/bin. I need to copy the Api.dll from there to $(TargetDir) for Entity Framework Migration.  eg:

```
    <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
        <Exec Command="echo copy /Y &quot;$(TargetDir)bin\Api.dll&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot;" />
    </Target>
```

The copy appears to work, but is not there when the build is completed.

- If I do the copy as a batch file with a directory listing before and after the file IS copied.
- But its not there when I try to do add-migration

So I guess the project build is recreating the Target folder after PostBuildEvent ???

The Api project builds OK but when I run add-migration fist I get:

```
 An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Api.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Api', version: '1.0.0'
    path: 'Api.dll'
```

The dll is not in $(TargetDir) but one folder lower in $(TargetDir)bin

Answer (score 1):

this is due to `RemoveRuntimeDependencies` task removes this assemblies. Add `<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput> to` .csproj`within`PropertyGroup.

Comment: Thank you! I have trying to track down this rogue cleanup for days!